# I need to know how to refactor the Dockerfile with Dotnet application

Tags: docker, devops, cicd

I need to refactor the Dockerfile of a Dotnet application which looks similar to the below.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80   
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj", "DockerExplained/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerExplained"
RUN dotnet build "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build  
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExplained.dll"]
```

where as i need to use ubuntu20.04 as base image with image layers and i was told not to mention the busterslim. Can anyone guide how to proceed on this.

========================================

Here is the fresh requirement for the file... requirement is to install everything inside the raw image of Ubuntu 20.04 and i am not able to package the image layers start FROM ubuntu 20.04
I get seven different images but i need everything to run inside the ubuntu 20.04..

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj", "DockerExplained/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerExplained"
RUN dotnet publish "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM ubuntu:20.04

#Runtime-deps

FROM debian:buster-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        \
# .NET Core dependencies
        libc6 \
        libgcc1 \
        libgssapi-krb5-2 \
        libicu63 \
        libssl1.1 \
        libstdc++6 \
        zlib1g \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure web servers to bind to port 80 when present
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 \
    # Enable detection of running in a container
    DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true
        
#Runtime

from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1-buster-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install .NET Core
RUN dotnet_version=3.1.3 \
    && curl -SL --output dotnet.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/Runtime/$dotnet_version/dotnet-runtime-$dotnet_version-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && dotnet_sha512='e3f6f9b81bc3828b60f7da5a5c341373dc17f971f1de3f2714adcca180a630a60d4b681166fe78434d8b2ce023d2d08eff4f1935ec664130b7f856fa8e1cac2b' \
    && echo "$dotnet_sha512 dotnet.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -ozxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

#ASPdotnet.3.1-busterslim

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:3.1-buster-slim

# Install ASP.NET Core
RUN aspnetcore_version=3.1.3 \
    && curl -SL --output aspnetcore.tar.gz https://dotnetcli.azureedge.net/dotnet/aspnetcore/Runtime/$aspnetcore_version/aspnetcore-runtime-$aspnetcore_version-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && aspnetcore_sha512='ced0b7c9faaf250fbee2c850e8941d47a17da06fa8e576d57063fa4bbc6c8435de6ab488b683d4a692cd622e24d9592f11608a1b358074167cf0b76024815611' \
    && echo "$aspnetcore_sha512  aspnetcore.tar.gz" | sha512sum -c - \
    && tar -ozxf aspnetcore.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet ./shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App \
    && rm aspnetcore.tar.gz


WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExplained.dll"]``
```

Comment: Please do not use images to post code. Post the contents of the dockerfile directly as text and format it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The tag list for the aspnet images can be found [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet) along with the OS versions in each image.

If you want to use Ubuntu 20.04, you need to change your base image to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-focal AS base
```

If you want the default Debian 10, you can just remove the 'buster-slim' part of the image tag so you get

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
```

As you can see in the list, `3.1` and `3.1-buster-slim` are the same image so if you use `3.1` you'll get the same image as you use now.

Edit: Dockerfile explanation, build / runtime

Here you create a temporary image called base which is based on the aspnet runtime image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
```

Then you create a temporary image called build based on the SDK image where you build your solution. Note that this has nothing to do with the image above.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj", "DockerExplained/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerExplained"
RUN dotnet build "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```

Then you create a new temporary image called publish based on the temporary build image

```
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
```

And finally you create the final image where you build upon your 'base' image from the top. Here you copy the published app from the 'publish' image.

```
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExplained.dll"]
```

As you can see, the final image is made from the first 3 lines + the last 4 lines in your Dockerfile. The middle part is where you build your solution and those bits of the Dockerfile aren't included in the final image.

Here's how you could structure it in a more simple way with only 2 steps: build and runtime/final.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj", "DockerExplained/"]
RUN dotnet restore "DockerExplained/DockerExplained.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerExplained"
RUN dotnet publish "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80   
COPY --from=build /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExplained.dll"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but if the constraint is to use 
1.Two different layers of image one as base image which i can use for other Dotnet application.
Multi-stage builds:
Preparatory steps like compilation and its required libraries should be made in a different stage.

2. Need to start with FROM ubuntu20.04 that is the criteria and in that case how would i proceed.
3. I need to reduce the size of the image as well. @Hans Kilian

Comment: I also found that buster is based on debian and focal is based on ubuntu, is there a way i can draft the Dockerfile with only ubuntu20.04 and avoid mentioning focal

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't care too much about the images used to build. They're only run when you build. The important image is your runtime image. You can definitely start from a base Ubuntu image and build your own runtime, but why would you? I'm pretty sure Microsoft makes a better image than I would be able to. If you look at what you do with the runtime image, you just set a workdir, expose a port, copy the published app and set an entrypoint. That's not a lot and there's really not much point in making something you can reuse.

Comment: If image size is important to you, you should use a image based on Alpine rather than Ubuntu. If you want to see how Microsoft have built their images, they're in https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/ in the `src` directory. The aspnet image is built on top of the runtime image which is built on top of runtime-deps which is based on the base OS image. If you want to build your own image, you can look at their Dockerfiles to see what they do.

Comment: Got it, Can you show me with the existing Dockerfile how can i use that ? I am bit confused and that would help me alot. what and where to mention the image for runtime and build.

Comment: Scratch-- https://github.com/debuerreotype/docker-debian-artifacts/blob/40788cbd2ff186239b1bf6ff63f3a506e43e5896/buster/Dockerfile
runtime-deps-- https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/5e9b849a900c69edfe78f6e0f3519009de4ab471/3.1/runtime/buster-slim/amd64/Dockerfile
runtime-- https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/5e9b849a900c69edfe78f6e0f3519009de4ab471/3.1/runtime/buster-slim/amd64/Dockerfile.  ASPdotnet-- https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/5e9b849a900c69edfe78f6e0f3519009de4ab471/3.1/aspnet/buster-slim/amd64/Dockerfile

Comment: I also understood the build process of dotnet from this https://marcroussy.com/2020/05/01/docker-build-process-for-dotnet/

Comment: @lakshminarayanan I've added a walkthrough of your Dockerfile at the bottom of my answer where I try to point out which parts are build parts and which parts are runtime parts.

Comment: You can't use `dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-focal` as your base build image? Maybe I'm not understanding why you want to base it on a raw ubuntu image, but I can't see any advantages to it. When you use Microsoft's images, you get images that are easy to use, tested and updated when updates come out.

Comment: > FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-focal AS baseWORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80 
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS build
{{
installing the dependencies of sdk 3.1- I would extract sdk 3.1 dockerfile
}}
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["DockerExplained/===
RUN dotnet restore ===
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerExplained"
RUN dotnet build ==
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerExplained.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from====
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExplained.dll"]''

Can you please correct me if im doing it right?

Comment: sorry code formatting is not working for me.. i had to post like this... Mentioning the above code in new answers..

Comment: I've added how I would structure it. I like having a build step and a runtime step in my Dockerfiles with the build first and the runtime last. You have 4 FROM statements and you really only need 2. You can of course change 'buster-slim' to 'focal' or just remove it and use the default '3.1' images. I've removed the `dotnet build` step as it's not necessary.

Comment: Thats really nice to see the new one. let me go through that

Comment: These are my Constraints and i need to modify the dockerfile
1.The component docker images should be based on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.“Dockerfile” statement: FROM ubuntu:20.04
2.We use pinned dependencies. This means that the detailed version of each installed dependency must be explicitly specified in the Dockerfile.
3.Preparatory steps like compilation and its required libraries should be made in a different stage.
See Docker documentation 
4.The application should not run as the root user. A system user and group should be created in the Dockerfile and the application started with this user.

Comment: please suggest on the file mentioned above in the answers section